# Chrome extension can't create cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, popup

Firstly, I'm crap at English, I hope you'll understand everything..

I have created a small extension on google chrome.
Basically it does this :

- When you click on the icon of the extension, it displays a form ( popup.html )
- When you click on the submi button, it create a new cookie ( popup.js )

**popup.html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"         target="_blank" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
          body {
          overflow-x: hidden;
          background-color: white;
          width: 170px !important;
          height: 200px;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="popup.js" langage="javascript"> </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <center>
          <form action="online.html"><input id="alertButton" type="submit" value="submit"></input>
          </form>
        </center>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**popup.js**

```
    function myAlert()
    {   
        chrome.cookies.set({url : "testing.com", domain : "www.testing.com", name : "name1", value: "value1", path : "/"}) ;
        alert("after");
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
    });
```

So yeah.... **It doesn't create any cookie at all.**
I don't understand, I've been trying to fix this for hours.
The alert("after") shows well.

I need an assist please, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok i found the solution, I think it was syntax error:
**popup.js**

        function myAlert()
        { 
         if ( getCookie() == true )
          return
         else
         chrome.cookies.set({"url" : "http://www.testing.com", "domain" :"www.testing.com", "name" : "name1", "value": "value1", "path" : "/"});
         
         
         alert("after");
        }

Comment: I removed the "resolved" tag from the subject, which is not how Stack Overflow works. Add an answer to this question, then mark it accepted. It would be polite to upvote the other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie does not work in chrome when you run the file locally.

You need to run this file from web server.

Like you can put this file into htdocs of xampp if you will use xampp, and run this like

```
localhost/popup.html
```

You can get the **Apache**(web server) and **Mysql**(database) into xampp software.

Answer (score 0):

you cant see it since you are running on your local machine ie C://documents...etc . You need a server. ie localhost/index.html. you can use aptana and create a web project in it.